# How to sub string and break word with different fields with RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have encounter issues about sub string with from input and store in destination fields with different field length.

I have four 35A input fields condition with if character at position 35A of input line 1 is not a space and first character of input line 2 is not space,
then will move last word of input line field 1 to destination field 2.Same rules will applied to destination field with line 2 ,3,4. It also will prompted  error
after movement input word if the destination fields length no enough long to store total four input fields.

Scenario 1:

`Input 1 35A: |No. 1241,Old Klang road,  Tom Cater| 
Input 2 35A: |rried ,58785 Windfall Stand  Johnan| 
Input 3 35A: | Stress bay   White hall     CHIGNA|
Input 4 35A: |LL ST JAMES                        |`

Expected result store to 4 line destination fields with 40A each of line.

`Destination Field 1 40A: |No. 1241,Old Klang road, Tom           |
Destination Field 2 40A: |Caterrried ,58785 Windfall Stand       |
Destination Field 3 40A: |Johnan Stress bay   White hall         |- The 'bay  ' world remain 
Destination Field 4 40A: |CHIGNALL ST JAMES                      |`

Scenario 2:

`Input 1 35A: |No. 1241,Old Klang road,  Tom Cater|
Input 2 35A: |rried ,58785 Windfall Stand  Johnan|
Input 3 35A: | Stress bay   White hall     CHIGNA|
Input 4 35A: |LL ST JAMES TAXES STATES STAND CITY|`

Expected result store to 4 line destination fields with 40A each of line.

`Destination Field 1 40A: |No. 1241,Old Klang road, Tom           |
Destination Field 2 40A: |Caterrried ,58785 Windfall Stand       |
Destination Field 3 40A: |Johnan Stress bay   White hall         |- The 'bay  ' world with space remain 
Destination Field 4 40A: |CHIGNALL ST JAMES TAXES STATES STAND CI|- Prompt error msg as the 'TY' no enough fit in the 40 length field`

Appreciated with any help,Thanks.Sorry with my poor English.

Comment: You can use `%checkr(' ',str)` to find the last non-blank character in the string.

Comment: I manage to find last non-blank character, but the issues is how to concatenate the correct position as per my expected result? any thought or idea logic?

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you trying to store in 40A when the data comes in as 35A?

Secondly, why are you reading/storing as multiple fields instead of a single field?  If you're using 5250 green screen.  Check out either the [CNTFLD (Continued-Entry Field)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakc/rzakcmstcntfld.htm) or the [WRDWRAP (Word Wrap)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakc/rzakcmstwrdwra.htm) keywords.  If you're working with a GUI or web based UI...it should be even easier...

If you absolutely must do what you've asked about...

I'd `%trim()` and concatenate all the input string into a single large one.  Then loop through..

```
string = %trim(Inp1) + %trim(Inp2) + %trim(Inp3) + %trim(Inp4);
searchFrom = 40;
strPos = 1;
for x = 1 to 4;
  endPos = %scanr(' ':string:searchFrom);
  destArr(x) = %subst(string:strPos:endPos);
  strPos = endPos + 1;
  searchFrom = strPos + 40;
endfor;
```

The above is missing any kind of error checking, but it should give you the idea.

**Note:**  `%scanr()` is new to v7.3.  If on an earlier version, you'd need to built your own `scan_rev()` function.

Comment: that won't handle the spaces properly though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the data comes in as 35A is the old legacy system remain unchange and the 40A is requirement.The %SCANR function still can use on V7R2 ?If cannot , any sample can refer for built in scan_rev()? How to prompt error for my Scenario 2 if total word cannot fit the destination field?

Comment: `%scanr` is a built-in that appeared in v7.3. It scans the string in reverse looking for a string. You should be able to do that with a for loop and `%substr`.

Comment: @DumAco In general this is not a site to get your code written for you. Show us what you have and we can help with specifics.

Comment: What is the different for %substr vs %subst ?Which 1 suit for my case?

Comment: [`%subst()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/bbsubs9.htm) is correct for RPGLE....`%substr()` is a typo...probably there's a `SUBSTR()` function in SQL.

Comment: how about %checkr?  checkr can use?

Comment: @DumAco, did you read the docs for `%checkr()`?  What do you think?